# integrate paypal payment with unity

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, paypal

i want to add Paypal payment through unity without direct the users to the web browser at all.

> https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/pay_paypal/dotnet?interactive=OFF&env=sandbox

I looked at this tutorial but at step 3 the user is asked to go through the web browser to log in,
There is any way do the log in process directly with .net / c# code through unity

thank you

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is only possible by including a browser (cause security reasons). C# has a [WebBrowser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx) class, which you could modify, so the user thinks it's in the game.
An other thing you can try is a [http request](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.httprequest(v=vs.110).aspx) via c# where you pass the username and the password to the website (but I don't know if this is possible with paypal).

Comment: thank you, this is exactly what i am looking for, a HTTP post request, directly to Paypal and getting a confirmation response (or failure) to the game itself without the web browser, but maybe you are right, maybe it cant be done because security reasons :/ @91378246